# Essential packages and multiple architectures on Debian

Tags: debian, aptitude, cpu-architecture

I have a working OS that runs 64 bit kernel but I want to use 32 bit versions of most packages because of limited memory on the machine. I need to keep some 64 bit drivers though as there is no 32 bit replacement.

I made the transition from full 64 bit system, but aptitude complains that essential packages are broken. It is likely that 32 bit crossgrade was requested but could not be fully completed. How can I keep the packages that I have already working?

For example, `bash` is requested (implied i386) and `bash:amd64` is installed, works but aptitude thinks it's broken while `dpkg -l` seems OK.

```
dpkg -l | grep bash   
ii  bash:amd64           4.4-5                  amd64
```

Should I change the architecture back to `amd64` and install `i386` versions of non-essentials instead?

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254418/difference-between-size-of-binaries-x86-64-vs-arm

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference in memory allocation between e. g. the 32- and 64-bit versions of `bash`?

Comment: With any sizable program the compiled code containing 64bit instructions are minuscule in comparison to the in memory data structures the program creates. Further there are other misnomers with 64bit. You will probably save 200K by program/library doing this on average. So for a whole system maybe 100-300MB?

Comment: `bash` was just one of essential packages that prevented full crossgrade. In my case, savings are roughly around 20% for the ones I care about. YMMV.

Comment: Don't you want to use the [x32 Debian port](https://wiki.debian.org/X32Port) instead?

Answer (score 2):

The system’s main architecture is the architecture of the `dpkg` package. This is also the default architecture for newly-installed packages, which I’m guessing is what you’re interested in.

As you’ve found out, `apt` ends up resolving dependencies in such a way that all essential packages need to be those matching the main architecture.

To resolve this situation while keeping `i386` as your main architecture, you’ll have to manually install all `i386` essential packages. You might be able to get `apt` to help you by switching back to `amd64` temporarily; then `aptitude search '~i~E'` will list all essential packages and you can manipulate that to download them all. If you already have some `i386` essential packages installed, that might not work and you’ll have to [download everything manually](https://packages.debian.org)...